# Putting ControlWrapper into a js function

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a bunch of controlwrappers for my google visualization dashboard in the form of

```
var compositeScorePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
   'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
   'containerId': 'compositeScorecontrol',
   'options': {
       'filterColumnLabel': 'compositeScore',
       'ui': {
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': false
             }
          }
        });
```

How can I create a function that does this where I enter in "compositeScore" and output this variable?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```
  function getWrapper(name) {
    result = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': name + 'control',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': name,
        'ui': {
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': false
        }
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
  var compositeScorePicker = getWrapper('compositeScore');
```

This will just change the containerId to be the name you pass in with "control" concatenated at the end, and will set the filterColumnLabel to the name you pass in.